# Start background process from shellscript then bring back to foreground later

Tags: shell, background-process

I'm trying to make a shell script that does the following:

- Start program x
- While x is running execute some commands, for example:

  ```
  echo "blabla" >> ~/blabla.txt
  ```
- After the execution of those commands program x should be running in the foreground, so that it can take user input.

So far I have:

```
~/x &
echo "blabla" >> ~/blabla.txt
```

However, I don't know how to move x back to the foreground. This is all called from a shell script so I don't know the job number of x to move to the foreground.

Note: everything has to be automated, no user interaction with the shell script should be needed.

Any suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: If program x is asking for user input, it should display on the terminal despite x running in background.

Answer (score 6):

Although absolutely don't understand why someone may need such script, and I'm sure than exists more elegant and more better/correct solution - but ok - the next demostrating how:

The script what going to background (named as `bgg`)

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 10)
do
    echo "bg: $i"
    sleep 1
done
read -p 'BGG enter something:' -r data
echo "$0 got: $data"
```

the main script (`main.sh`)

```
set -m   #this is important

echo "Sending script bgg to background - will cycle 10 secs"
./bgg & 2>/dev/null

echo "Some commands"
date
read -r -p 'main.sh - enter something:' fgdata
echo "Main.sh got: ==$fgdata=="

jnum=$(jobs -l | grep " $! " | sed 's/\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/')
echo "Backgroung job number: $jnum"

echo "Now sleeping 3 sec"
sleep 3
echo "Bringing $jnum to foreground - wait until the BG job will read"
fg $jnum
```

run the `./main.sh` - and the result will be something like

```
Sending bgg to background - will cycle 10 secs
Some commands
Mon Mar  3 00:04:57 CET 2014
main.sh - enter something:bg: 1
bg: 2
bg: 3
bg: 4
bg: 5
qqbg: 6
qqqqq
Main.sh got: ==qqqqqqq==
Backgroung job number: 1
Now sleeping 3 sec
bg: 7
bg: 8
bg: 9
Bringing 1 to foreground - wait until the BG job will read
./bgg
bg: 10
BGG enter something:wwwwwww
./bgg got: wwwwwww
```

Comment: `set -m   #this is important` That is all I needed, this is important indeed!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fg` to bring the last background process to foreground